# Extend string to a list inside a list

Tags: python

```
list = [ [ ] ]
money = int(raw_input("Enter the total money spent: "))
```

In this program I want to extend the money variable to the list inside the list, so when I print it, it appears as [ ["money variable input"] ]. I am also planning on adding other items to the same element. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Note that you should not use `list` as an identifier in Python, since it is the name of a built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the "append" method on the first element of list.  Since list is a multi-dimensional array, the first element is an array, which will have an "append" method.  Example:

```
list = [ [ ] ]
money = 10
list[0].append(money)
list
```

Prints [[10]]

Comment: Is there a way to add other items to the appended element?

Comment: Refer to the right array, then just call append.  If what you want is to put yet another nested array inside, then just construct a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, name your variable something other than `list`, maybe `lst`.

Secondly, you should do it as:

```
lst[0].append(money)
```

or simply:

```
lst[0].append(int(raw_input("Enter the total money spent: ")))

>>> print lst
Enter the total money spent: 5
[[10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
input = int(raw_input("Enter the total money spent: "))
# 'list' is an python keyword, try not to use it as a variable name
myList[0].extend( input )
```

Just out of curiosity why do you have a list within a list for only one element? I hope you're adding more elements later!

Comment: Im planning on having different inputs for different times, and im going to be doing different operations to different times